# Is there any way to remove/ hide this field from cart and checkout page in the word press website

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, hook-woocommerce, woothemes, wordpress-shortcode

I am using a travel booking theme. In the theme the minimum adult count default set to 1. Is there any way to remove/hide this field from cart and checkout page in the word press woo commerce website?

[image: Screenshot of what I am describing]

Comment: Hi, without any code nor link to the website nobody will be able to help, you should try updating your post

Comment: I would second the above comment. Can you share the name of the theme or a link to the themes website as part of the question? It is likely what you are trying to achieve will be covered in the theme's documentation but it will be difficult to help you without any code examples or further information.